# Where does Azure Portal save its user UI customization/preferences (e.g. dashboard design)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azureportal

I'm starting to design a React dashboard where users are enabled to customize the dashboard's layout. Also, within the dashboard will be charts that will display results of analysis on financial data. I would like the user to be able to save a setting like:

1. In the first box, I need a scatter plot where x-axis is volatility of MOVE Index and y-axis is volatility of MSFT. I need the scatter plot to show data for 63 datapoints where latest is today.
2. Every time I visit the website's dashboard, the frontend will fetch the data automatically from the API (data updated daily) so charts will also show updated data. But then, if user change the x-axis data to be volatility of NDX, it must be saved.
3. If user does not need that box any more, he can close that and it the UI settings will be stored accordingly

### Edit

The above website has auth in Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should look into using [indexeddb](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb), it is supported by most modern browsers and can be used to save the sort of data you have been talking about.

This would work for a local storage solution. If you require the data to be associated with a user account and accessible from multiple different machines you would need to look into some sort of hosted database storage which your application can interface with e.g. a mySQL server.